# Can you use 'webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' for a tbody element on an ipad?

Tags: ipad

Does anyone know if it's possible to get the tbody to scroll with the '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' property on an ipad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think webkit allows overflown tbodys with out setting header and body to display:blocks, and also setting the widths of the individual table cells. Here is a good [link on the subject](http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/) .

That said -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch will work on anything that is set to overflow. I have a working example on a tbody as well.